# How can I create check box grid with labels using iText Java?

Tags: itext

I want to use  `p:selectManyCheckbox` like checkbox grid functionality in PDF using `iText` Java.

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve. Right now, it is hard to understand your question. Please elaborate. What do you mean when you write *checkbox grid functionality*? What have you tried? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I want to add dynamic check box grid just like PrimeFaces  p:selectManyCheckbox (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml)
in a pdf file usnig iText
I am working on PdfPTable . I have used PdfPCell in which I am able to add checkbox but can not  add  label for that checkbox in same PdfPCell .